# Magento Fatal Error - Call to a member function getId() on a non-object

Tags: php, magento, zapier

When connecting Magento to Zapier the response is an error code:

```
authorization failed: junk after document element: line 2, column 0
```

Further searching shows the cause is an IWD Sales Rep Extension in Magento.

> **Fatal error**:  Call to a member function getId() on a non-object in
>   **/home/moove/public_html/app/code/community/IWD/SalesRepresentative/Model/Observer.php**
>   on line **452**

Below is line 449 - 459

```
}

public function getUserSettings(){
    $userId = Mage::getModel('admin/session')->getUser()->getId();
    $item = Mage::getModel('salesrep/users')->load($userId,'user_id');
    if ($item->getId()){

        return $item;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Appreciate anyone's help resolving this issue.

Comment: Try to var_dump your `$userId` and `$item` first. What is the result ?

Answer (score 0):

Try

$userId =Mage::getSingleton('admin/session')->getUser()->getId();